# How do I display the text contents of a div tag in a tool tip without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I would like to be able to display the context of HTML element to show inside a tool tip. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Ideally I would like to see *test* show up in my tooltip. But that does not happen.

We don't use jQuery in our code base so I can't use any jQuery plugins. But we do write JavaScript code as and when required. My set up is given below

My div is as follows:

```
<div class="tooltip message">test</div>
```

My CSS set up:

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip.message:before {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tooltip.message:after {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content:"";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

My fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7LNJc/3/

Comment: Is this a job opportunity you're advertising? How much does it pay? Or are you asking for free code?

Comment: "I would like to see test show up" What browser are you on? Works for me.

Comment: @Adam This is not a job opportunity nor I am asking for free code. I did try to get it to work, but I have not been successful. Hence my request for assistance.

Comment: @Kartik - what did you try? It's encouraged on SO to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. The CSS and the fiddle is what I have tried. I would like the text content of the div to show up as tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `class='tooltip message'` an id, like:

```
<div class='tooltip message' id='test'>test</div>
```

Review the following:

```
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
```

Now `E('test')` is the same as `document.getElementById('id')`, so you never need it again;

```
var test = E('test').innerHTML; // holds the html
```

If the Element has a `value` attribute, like an input then you would do:

```
var test = E('test').value; // holds the html value attribute
```

To assign new `innerHTML` or a `value`, it's like:

```
var test = E('test');
test.innerHTML = 'some text';
```

or

```
test.value = 'some value';
```

You could even do this:

```
E('test').innerHTML = 'some text';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether it's important to you that a custom tooltip behavior be used, rather than the default tooltip functionality already in HTML.  If the custom tooltip isn't necessary, then you could use the `title` attribute to generate a tooltip withour resorting to JavaScript:

`<div class="tooltip message" title="test">test</div>`

Comment: I would like the text content in the div tag as a tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS :hover selector on div element instead tooltip specified by attribute `title`. it provides kind of toolkip visually.

```
div.tooltip {
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.tooltip:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000000;
}
```